# If $X_t=\int_0^t \sigma _s\,\mathrm d W_s$, how can I prove that $\mathrm d \left<X\right>_t=\sigma _t^2\,\mathrm d t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $\sigma $ a very nice function. Let $X_t:=\int_0^t \sigma _s\,\mathrm d W_s$. We define $$\left<X\right>_t=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}(X_{t_{i+1}^{(n)}}-X_{t_i^{(n)}})^2$$
where the limit is taken in the probability sense and $0=t_0^{(n)}<t_{1}^{(n)}<...<t_{m_n}^{(n)}=t$ is s.t. $\max_{i=0,...,m_n-1}|t_{i+1}^{(n)}-t_i^{(n)}|\to 0$ when $n\to \infty $.

**Attempts : no need to read the steps 1 and step 2, just step 3 is relevant.**

- **Step 1:** Suppose $\sigma $ is of the form $\sigma _s=Y\boldsymbol 1_{[u,v)}$ where $Y$ is $\mathcal F_u-$measurable. Take $(t_i^{(n)})$ being a partition of $[u,v]$ s.t. $\max_{i}|t_{i+1}^{(n)}-t_i^{(n)}|\to 0$ when $n\to \infty $.

Then
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}(X_{t_{i+1}^{(n)}}-X_{t_i^{(n)}})^2-\int_0^t\sigma _s^2\,\mathrm d s\right)^2\right]\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{m_n-1}\mathbb E\left[Y^4\Big((W_{t_{i+1}^{(n)}}-W_{t_i^{(n)}})^2-(t_{i+1}^{(n)}-t_i^{(n)})\Big)\Big((W_{t_{j+1}^{(n)}}-W_{t_j^{(n)}})^2-(t_{j+1}^{(n)}-t_j^{(n)})\Big)\right]\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}E\left[Y^4\Big((W_{t_{i+1}^{(n)}}-W_{t_i^{(n)}})^2-(t_{i+1}^{(n)}-t_i^{(n)})\Big)^2\right]\\
&=2\mathbb E[Y^4]\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}(t_{i+1}^{(n)}-t_i^{(n)})^2\\
&\leq 2\mathbb E[Y^4](v-u)\max_{i=0,...,m_n-1}|t_{i+1}^{(n)}-t_i^{(n)}|\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.
\end{align*}

- **Step 2:** Now, if $\sigma $ is a predictable process, the step 1 applies.
- **Step 3:** If $\sigma $ is more general (i.e. s.t. $\mathbb E\int_0^t \sigma _s^2\,\mathrm d s<\infty $), there is a sequence $(\sigma ^n)$ of predictable process s.t. $\sigma _n\to \sigma $ in $L^2$. In particular $$\int_0^t \sigma ^n_s\,\mathrm d W_s\to \int_0^t \sigma _s\,\mathrm d W_s,\quad \text{in }L^2.$$

Let $(t_i^{(m)})$ a partition of $[0,t]$ s.t. $0=t_0^{(m)}<...<t_{k_m}^{(m)}=t$ s.t. $\max_{i=0,...,k_m-1}|t_{i+1}^{(m)}-t_i^{(m)}|\to 0$ when $m\to \infty $.

I know by step 2 that $$\lim_{m\to \infty }\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k_m-1}\left(\int_{t_{i}^{(m)}}^{t_{i+1}^{(m)}}\sigma _s^{(n)}\,\mathrm d W_s\right)^2-\int_0^t(\sigma _s^n)^2\,\mathrm d s\right)^2\right]=0.$$

From that, how can I prove that

$$\lim_{m\to \infty }\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k_m-1}\left(\int_{t_{i}^{(m)}}^{t_{i+1}^{(m)}}\sigma _s\,\mathrm d W_s\right)^2-\int_0^t(\sigma _s)^2\,\mathrm d s\right)^2\right]=0 \ \ ?$$

If this way doesn't work, maybe is there an other way ?

Comment: Hi not an answer, but if nothing appears tilll your deadline: i know, that you can solve similar things with argumentation via finite and not definite Variation of Wiener processes; for quadratic Variation of Wiener Processes you can show $[W_i,W_j]=t\delta_{ij}$ with similar arguments. I can send you my BA-Thesis if you want (on temp mail address). Furthermore it should be shown in karatzas shreve brownian motion and stochastic calculus. Greets

Comment: @Probabilitytheoryapprentice There's an answer below. I request you to have a look, since you will appreciate it better than me for sure. I liked it , to be fair, it looks correct to me. I did find the same material in Karatzas-Shreve as well!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon proof below looks good to me. But to be honest: you really need the finite Variation condition $E\int_0^T \sigma_s^2\,ds < \infty$ because in general, $X$, $ X^2 -A$ are not martingales; on the other hand, you can show the same statement for local martingales and semimartingales if you have to weaken your assumption.

Comment: @Probabilitytheoryapprentice I see your point, the finite variation condition is very much required for this proof to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume $E\int_0^T \sigma_s^2\,ds < \infty$. Then the usual way to show that $\langle X \rangle_t = \int_0^t \sigma_s^2\,ds =: A_t$ is by showing that $X_t := \int_0^t \sigma_s dW_s$ is a martingale, and that $X^2 -  A$ is a martingale. This property characterizes the quadratic variation and will prove your claim.

Take simple $\sigma^{(n)} \to \sigma$ converging in the sense that $E\int_0^T |\sigma_s-\sigma^{(n)}_s|^2\,ds \to 0$. For simple $\sigma^{(n)}$ the martingale and quadratic variation properties are easy to check. Let $I^{(n)}_t := \int_0^t \sigma^{(n)}_s\,dW_s$ and $A^{(n)}_t := \int_0^t|\sigma^{(n)}_s|^2 \,ds$.
First check the martingale property.
Fix $s \leq t \leq T$.

$$
E[I^{(n)}_t|\mathcal{F}_s] = I^{(n)}_s
$$
By the Ito isometry for simple functions, the RHS tends to $X_s$ in $L^2$, and since the integrand of the LHS converges to $X_t$ in $L^2$ and the conditional expectation is a contraction on $L^p$ for any $p \geq 1$ (use that $E[E[Y | \mathcal{F}]^p]] \leq E[Y^p]$ by conditional Jensen and tower property for any $Y, \mathcal{F}$), we find that $E[I^{(n)}_t|\mathcal{F}_s] \to E[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s]$ in $L^2$ as well, showing $E[X_t |\mathcal{F}_s] = X_s$. Thus $X$ is a martingale.

Similarly we can check the quadratic variation as follows.
By the properties for simple integrands, we have
$$
E[(I^{(n)}_t)^2 - A^{(n)}_t|\mathcal{F}_s] = (I_s^{(n)})^2 - A^{(n)}_s
$$
Then since $(I_s^{(n)})^2 - A^{(n)}_s \to X^2_s-A_s$ in $L^1$ (definition of $\sigma^{(n)} \to \sigma$ for the second term, isometry for simple processes for the first term) and
$(I_t^{(n)})^2 - A^{(n)}_t \to X^2_t-A_t$ in $L^1$ plus the fact that the conditional expectation is a contraction on $L^1$ shows that $X^2-A$ is a martingale.
By uniqueness of the quadratic variation, we find that $A = \langle X \rangle$.

Comment: You may be nullUser, but you know your material very well, almost surely. +1

Comment: So, I can't prove it as I tried to do ?

Comment: @Bruce, I would not go so far as to say that you __cannot__ prove it that way. However, I am not aware of any book or proof that __does__ prove it that way. My guess is that it is indeed possible through sufficient struggle, but it may involve reproving the existence and uniqueness of quadratic variation in the proof.